# mat-select display different value than mat-options selected value

Tags: angular-material, angular6

I have a mat-select dropdown, here I am looping through my frequencyArr object.

**In ts**

```
frequencyArr = [
{key : "Once daily", abbriviation : '0-0-1'},
{key : "Twice daily", abbriviation : '1-0-1'},
{key : "Thrice daily", abbriviation : '1-1-1'},
{key : "Four times a day", abbriviation : '1-1-1-1'}
  ]
```

**In html**

```
<mat-select placeholder="frequency" formControlName="frequency" required>                             
    <mat-option *ngFor="let frequency of frequencyArr" [value]="frequency.abbriviation">
        <span>{{frequency.key }} : {{ frequency.abbriviation}}</span>
    </mat-option>
</mat-select>
```

What I am trying to do is when open the dialog it will show object key : object value-

```
<span>{{frequency.key }} : {{ frequency.abbriviation}}</span>
```

[image]

This is fine, but when I select the option it should show only frequency.key into selected field which is not happening.

[image]

I tried googling but did not find anything for this case. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 17):

You can do the following to accomplish this.

Set your value to `frequency.key`

```
[value]="frequency.key"
```

Then use `<mat-select-trigger` to display the `frequency.value` from your `formControl`

```
<mat-select-trigger>
      {{frequency.value}}
    </mat-select-trigger>
```

**Stackblitz**

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-wxv1wv?embed=1&file=app/select-custom-trigger-example.html

Comment: This is not working. In my case frequency is a FormGroup element instead of FormControl. I am not sure if that is the reason?

Comment: You are correct, please see revised stackblitz. `{{myFormGroup.controls['frequency'].value}}`

Answer (score 16):

You may achieve that by using a mat-select-trigger and a template reference as bellow:

```
<mat-select placeholder="frequency" required #select>
  <mat-select-trigger>
    {{ select.value?.abbriviation }}
  </mat-select-trigger>
  <mat-option *ngFor="let frequency of frequencyArr" [value]="frequency">{{frequency.key }} : {{ frequency.abbriviation}}</mat-option>
</mat-select>
```

Answer (score 0):

Updated @GCSDC answer, added the condition to display one single selected item while selecting multiple checkbox. Pass the ID (#selectPartner) to trigger the selected data

```
<div class="col">
              <mat-select
                [formControl]="partnerFormControl"
                multiple
                placeholder="{{
                  generalAppSettings?.filterVariables?.partnerText
                }}"
                class="dropdownFilters"
                *ngIf="generalAppSettings?.filterVariables?.showPartnerFilter"
                [(value)]="partnerValue"
                [disabled]="disablePartner"
                panelClass="findPartnerPanel"
                [ngClass]="disablePartner ? 'disableEvent' : ''"
                #selectPartner
              >
                <mat-select-trigger>
                  @if ((selectPartner.value?.length || 0) >= 1) {
                  <span
                    *ngFor="
                      let data of generalAppSettings?.filterVariables
                        ?.partnerAbbr
                    "
                  >
                    {{ selectPartner.value[0] == data.key ? data.key : '' }}
                  </span>
                  }
                </mat-select-trigger>
                <mat-option
                  *ngFor="
                    let option of generalAppSettings?.filterVariables
                      ?.partnerAbbr
                  "
                  [value]="option.key"
                >
                  {{ option.value }}
                </mat-option>
              </mat-select>
            </div>
```

[image]